# DataStudio: How to filter greater than '>' without 'ADD A FILTER'

Tags: looker-studio

Got a salary column in big query.

Trying to figure out a way to filter the salary with logical operators without specifying a custom filter(ADD A FILTER) in DataStudio.

I would like to perform the following operation: 
salary > 5000000000000000 for example.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144), with the Dimension set to Salary, and the Filter Control set to the *Search All* view, so that comparison operators (>, >=, <, <=, =) can be used to filter Metrics quickly.

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d54a1eac-2d36-4a11-ba85-b22aa53c7459) (Google Sheets Embedded) as well as a GIF showing the process.[image]

Answer (score 0):

love answering my own question:)

So far i only see one way to filter numbers by using CASE

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724